# How to edit (or even find) the file called common.mk to edit the default compiler?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, makefile

Here's the background: I need to download some code form github but I don't know much about Linux. I ran the command `git clone` with the desired code and got it and stored it in a folder. Then, as instructed, I opened the folder to run `make`, which I was advised that would give me some complications. The main one is that I need to change the default compiler to gcc before running the command. From what I understood from posts I found is that I need to change or to edit somehow the common.mk file. The problem is I can't even find it, or acces it, or even know if it exists.

This is the question, how do I edit the common.mk file to change the default compiler? Or equivalently, if there is no need to go through the common.mk file to change the compiler, what's the way to change it? I've searched quite a lot, but as I said, I'm quite new to all this and don't understand the 90% of the technicalities used. Sites that have helped me a bit until now are [this](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/qnxcar2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino.prog%2Ftopic%2Fmake_convent_COMMONMAN.html), which is quite short and doesn't explain much; and [this](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.2/neutrino/prog/make_convent.html), which for me is really difficult to figure out.

To explain my situation, I only know the most basic Linux commands like `cd` and things like that, I don't even know if there are other ways of running commands from somewhere else besides the cmd. All of the stuff that the second link explains, I can more or less understand them but don't know how to apply them on the cmd, or even if they can be applied via cmd. Any help is welcome.

**Edit:** The github from where I downloaded that said to change the default compiler gave [this link](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/platform2/+/HEAD/common-mk/common.mk) as an explanation on how to do it, but I don't understand anything here.

Comment: Hello @Mr. Nobody - interesting question - can you provide your approach to find the mentioned file?

Answer (score 0):

The usual `make` variable for the C compiler is `CC`, so if it's just *to change the default compiler to gcc*, this could be done by `make CC=gcc`.

Comment: I already tried this, but it gives me this error: If you want to permanently set the default compiler to gcc for all future compilations, please update the "CC" variable in "common.mk"
Error: Could find compiler = gcc
Please either set "CC" in "common.mk" or via the command-line, "make CC=yourcompiler"
And please check that the specified compiler is in your "$PATH" variable
../common.mk:150: *** .  Stop.

Comment: Is `gcc` installed on your system?  If you type `gcc --version` at the command prompt, does it succeed or fail?

Comment: Yes, apparently this was the problem, I thought my attempt of installing gcc had been unsuccessful, and I hadn't noticed it, once I did it it executed properly.